# Copy object attribute value, without copying the attribute itself

Tags: python, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I have written some code in Python. I have a class `Board`, which requires a list of lists as an input (`grid`), to give an initial value to the object. Below, I want to initialize a second `Board` instance with the value of the first. However, from this point forward I don't want the value of the second instance to update with that of the first.

Is there a way to do this? Currently, I get `List[1].value[0][0] = 50`, but I want it to remain as it's initial value!

```
List =[]
List = [Board(grid =grid)]
List.append(Board(grid = List[0].value))
List[0].value[0][0] = 50
List[1].value
```

Comment: You can make a shallow copy, like `.append(Board(grid=List[0].value[:]))`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem looks like `value` is a list of lists, may need `copy.deepcopy()`

Comment: Thank you very much - copy.deepcopy() worked perfectly!